# How do I make "at"-tasks repeat at a specific time?

Tags: scheduling, at

I want to schedule a script to run every Monday at 9am. How can I do this?

I can only find examples for given days, not repeating things with `at`.

Cron is not a solution.

Comment: Why no rerun the at commant at the end of the script ? e.g. at mon 9hr

Comment: `at` is for aperiodic tasks, `cron` for periodic ones... `cron` *is* the droid you are looking for.

Comment: @Archemar pls post this as answer! :)

Comment: @somelooser28533 Why is `cron` not an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the `at`-script call itself once it's done.

```
# cat t.txt
true
cat t.txt | at 9am mon
# bash t.txt
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 680 at Mon Sep  8 09:00:00 2014
#
```

Just replace `true` with your actual script.

Comment: can someonr (Bernhard ? ) explain why my editing fail ?

Comment: Your code block needed to be separated from the previous line by an empty line for the parser to recognise it as separate. When editing posts, you check the live preview underneath the source text to check if stuff has come out right.

Answer (score 3):

`at` can only schedule a command to be run once.

You can get around this be making the job schedule itself again, as well as executing your command.

Example:

~/myJob.txt:

```
at -f ~/myJob.txt +1 week ; echo "It's 9:00 AM on Monday!"
```

Then you just schedule it once to begin the cycle:

`at -f ~/myJob.txt 9am monday`

Comment: The `+1 week` should be `now +1 week`. Some versions of `at` will otherwise fail with `syntax error: garbled time`. Happened to me just now on RHEL 8 with `at` version `3.1.20`.